# Codeigniter paginate search results not working from page 2 onwards

Tags: codeigniter, search, pagination

I has problem to implement CI pagination to my search page, my links for the pagination is like `http://localhost/ci/search/2` (page 2) and so on, however my query can populate search results when it was first loaded, when I clicked on the page 2 onwards, it shown `No items in database`, I tried echo `$this->db->last_query()` to check my query in page 2, it shown `SELECT * FROM ('products') WHERE MATCH (name, manufacturer) AGAINST ("") LIMIT 2, 3` where missing the keywords to search and the LIMIT values is incorrect, can someone please give me an advise on what's wrong in code?

**Model:**

```
public function do_search_count($keywords)
{
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM products WHERE MATCH (name, manufacturer) AGAINST ('".$keywords."')";
    $q = $this->db->query($sql);
    $row = $q->row();
    return $row->cnt;
}

public function do_search($keywords, $limit, $per_page)
{
    $this->db->escape($keywords);
    $this->db->where('MATCH (name, manufacturer) AGAINST ("'.$keywords.'") LIMIT '.$limit.', '.$per_page, NULL, FALSE);
    $query = $this->db->get('products');

    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        return $query->result();
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

public function searchterm_handler($searchterm)
{
    if($searchterm)
    {
        $this->session->set_userdata('searchterm', $searchterm);
        return $searchterm;
    }
    elseif($this->session->userdata('searchterm'))
    {
        $searchterm = $this->session->userdata('searchterm');
        return $searchterm;
    }
    else
    {
        $searchterm = '';
        return $searchterm;
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
function search()
{
    $keywords = $this->input->post('search');

    $searchterm = $this->db_model->searchterm_handler($this->input->get_post('search', TRUE));
    $limit = ($this->uri->segment(2) > 0) ? $this->uri->segment(2) : 0;

    $config['base_url'] = base_url('search');
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->db_model->do_search_count($searchterm);
    $config['per_page'] = 3;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 2;
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
    $choice = $config['total_rows'] / $config['per_page'];
    $config['num_links'] = round($choice);  

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $data['results'] = $this->db_model->do_search(trim($keywords), $limit, $config['per_page']);
    $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $data['searchterm'] = $searchterm;

    $data['total'] = count($data['results']);
    $data['title'] = 'Search';

    $this->load->view('header', $data);
    $this->load->view('search', $data);
    $this->load->view('footer', $data);
}
```

**View:**

```
<div class="page-header"><h2>Search Result(s): <?php echo $total ?></h2></div>
<div>
<?php
if(is_array($results)){
    echo $this->db->last_query();
?>
<table width="40%" class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Manufacturer</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php
    foreach($results as $item){
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $item->name ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $item->manufacturer ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $item->price ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</table>
<?php
}else{
    echo 'No items in database! '.$this->db->last_query();;
}
?>
</div>

<div><?php echo $pagination ?></div>
```

**Search form view located in header file:**

```
<div class="header-search">
            <?php
            if($this->uri->segment(1) != 'search'){
                $this->session->unset_userdata('searchterm');
                $searchterm = '';
            }

            $form_attr = array('class' => 'form-wrapper cf');
            echo form_open('search', $form_attr);
            $search_attr = array('name'=>'search', 'id'=>'search', 'value'=>$searchterm, 'placeholder'=>'company, place, keywords etc...', 'required'=>'required');
            echo form_input($search_attr);
            $btn_attr = array('name' => 'btn_search', 'id' => 'btn_search', 'type' => 'submit', 'content' => 'search');
            echo form_button($btn_attr);
            echo form_close(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you debug the `$searchterm` variable in your controllers `search()` method when you are on a paginated url? It may not be returning a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appear to be several problems with your code:

Firstly your `$keywords` variable is taken from the post data, and the post data will be cleared as soon as you are redirected to a paginated page. You need to either pass this value in the url string or save it to the session.

Secondly your passing post data into your models `searchterm_handler()` method. As above, there is no post data to send to the method on a paginated page.

If you expect you won't be sending data as a parameter you need to set a default value for that parameter:

```
public function searchterm_handler($searchterm = null)
{

}
```

If you don't do this you will get an error like:

```
Warning: Missing argument 1 in call to searchterm_handler() in ...
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are getting the data for query from $_POST array. When you navigate the to second page using a link the search data is not posted again. Ideally you need to save the search term in to a cookie and use it when nothing is posted.

Also you can store the search term in the URL using function $this->uri->assoc_to_uri($_POST) and append to the base url, then retrieve the data back using using $this->uri->uri_to_assoc();

You can also generate the code for search with pagination at http://www.thephpcode.com